# Post via (ajax/javascript) to django view printing empty queryset

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to use more vanilla javascript instead if jquery. I have no problem making ajax calls with $.post but I can't seem to get it to work with vanilla javascript. This is my ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addAssignment').click(function () {
        $('#addAssignmentModal').modal('toggle');
    });

    $('#submitAssignment').click(function () {
        if(checkModal()){
            var assignment = {
                title: $('#newAssignmentTitle').val(),
                type: $('#assignmentSelection').val(),
                date: $('#newAssignmentDate').val(),
                details: $('#newAssignmentDetails').val()
            }

            console.log(assignment);
            submitAssignment(assignment);
        }
    });
});

function submitAssignment(assignment) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //Do stuff
        }
    };
    request.open("POST", '/data/api/create-assignment/', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
    //assignment is equal to: {title: "Title", type: "Homework", date: "02/18/2017", details: "Detais"}
    request.send(JSON.stringify(assignment));
}
```

When I try and print out the data in my Djano view, it prints out an empty queryset every time.

```
def createAssignment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST) # this prints an empty queryset
        # assignment = Assignments()
        # assignment = request.POST.get('assignment')
        # assignment.save()
        data = {}
        data['status'] = "Success"

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
    else:
        data = {}
        data['status'] = "Data must be sent via POST"

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

How do I prepare my data and receive it properly?

UPDATE:

I was able to get this working. The ajax call stays the same. In order to print the data in my django view, I used the following code:

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
body = json.loads(body_unicode)
print(body)
```

Printing body gives the following:

> {'details': 'Here are some details', 'title': 'Title', 'date': '02/18/2017', 'type': 'Homework'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
body = json.loads(body_unicode)
print(body)
```